# Convert sql query to jpql

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

Can Anyone help me to convert this query to jpql query

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM property p JOIN address a USING(a_id) JOIN address pa ON p.post_a_id = pa.a_id " +
            "JOIN section s ON s.p_id = p.p_id " +
            "WHERE p.organization_id = :orgId AND p.name ILIKE " +
            "ANY(SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT CONCAT('%', UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(:search, ' ')), '%'))))",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Property> findPropertiesByCreatorIdAndName(@Param("creatorId") Long creatorId,
                                                    @Param("search") String search,
                                                    Pageable pageable);
```

It needs to be here

```
 @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"sections", "address", "customFields", "postAddress"})
@Query("FROM Property p WHERE p.organizationId = :orgId AND p.name LIKE " +
        "ANY( UNNEST( ARRAY(SELECT CONCAT('%', UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(:search, ' ')), '%'))))")
 findPropertiesByCreatorIdAndName(@Param("creatorId") Long creatorId,
                                                    @Param("search") String search,
                                                    Pageable pageable);
```

The main difficulty is to convert this peace if query

```
ANY( UNNEST( ARRAY(SELECT CONCAT('%', UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(:search, ' ')), '%'))))
```

Comment: Without seeing the JPA entity mapping, it will be difficult for someone to tell how to map this query to JPQL.

Comment: Actually I am interested in this peace of query 
"ANY(SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT CONCAT('%', UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(:search, ' ')), '%'))))",

Comment: The rest I know ho to convert

Comment: What's the reason for the conversion? JPALQ does not know UNNEST and ARRAY and STRING_TO_ARRAY

Comment: Does JPAQL know some alternatives for this functions ?

Comment: `@EntityGraph` & `@Query` both will not work together

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I tested that they are not worked together and it's logical in a sense there is a possibility for completely different merging both is not possible